# How to run script from command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a script in my `lib/config/my_script.rb` which make a synchronization from MAIN database to my Database. 
How i can run it from command line? And it will be working?

Comment: what system are you using?windows/unix..

Comment: As far as running it from command line goes, you can run it using `ruby lib/config/my_script.rb`. But we cannot answer whether it will work or not without looking at any code. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ruby my_script.rb
```

I also wanted to provide a Ruby quick reference guide that will give you additional information on command line arguments for the ruby command as well as a wealth of other information on Ruby.

**Ruby Quick Reference Guide:** http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby lib/config/my_script.rb
```

or

```
./lib/config/my_script.rb
```